# Why can't corner flags be less than 1.5 Meters?

Tags: rules, football, history

How come in football corner flags can't be smaller than 1.5 Meters high? Is there a safety hazard?

Comment: Can't find anything that says why, but I would assume it is due to safety, since it is also forbidden for the flags to have a pointed top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a safety hazard.

As most players' torsos are just under 1.5m off the ground, there is a risk of damage to vital organs if a player was to fall on top of the flag, especially with great force.